# Динамические добавленный элементы с помощью динамических элементов не работают JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

Есть таблица с кнопкой "+". При нажатии на нее добавляется новая строка с той же кнопкой, а в пред. строке кнопка удаляется. Использую делегированную обработку событий. На первый динамический объект код срабатывает. А на последующие просто копируется предыдущий (второй) динамический объект.

```
    //HTML
<table id="communication-methods" cols="5">
  <tr>
    <td class="method-communication">Телефон:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="phone" id="main-phone" value="1" checked>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="whatidtext" id="number-phone">
    </td>
    <td id="tr-button-add" class="whatidtd">
      <input type="button" id="button-add" class="button-add" value="+">
    </td>
    </tr>
    // след. строки, не относящиеся к вопросу
    <tr></tr>

    //JQ 
function AddRow (ValRadio, ValText, ValTR) {
  ValRadio++;
  i = 1; i++;
  ValText =+ i;
  NewValTR =+ i;
  $("#button-add").closest("tr").after("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"phone\" id=\"main-phone\" value="+ValRadio+"></td><td></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"whatidtext\" id=\"number-phone"+ValText+"\"></td><td id="+NewValTR+" class=\"whatidtd\"><input type=\"button\" id=\"button-add\" class=\"button-add\" value=\"+\"></td></tr>");
  $("#"+ValTR).text("");   
}

$("#communication-methods").on("click", "#button-add", function() {
  TextInputVal = $('.whatidtext')[$('.whatidtext').length -1];
    if (TextInputVal.value == "") {
      // лейбл что типа пусто
    } else {
      Textinput = $('.whatidtext')[$('.whatidtext').length -1].id;              
      TR = $('.whatidtd')[$('.whatidtd').length -1].id;
      Radio = $('#main-phone')[$('#main-phone').length -1].value;            
      AddRow(Radio, Textinput, TR);
    }
 });
```